# How to make an authenticated user persist using a cookie

Tags: php, security

I am making a registration/login system with php. I think I have all the initial login stuff worked out(hashing password with salt, store in db...).

My question is in regard to keeping a user logged in between pages after their initial login. The way I understand it is that one method is to have a table of sessions on your server that stores a random unique id for each user and to store that id in a cookie on the user's computer. This way for each page they load all you do is lookup their session id in your database.

What I don't understand is how is that is secure? Couldn't somebody just sniff the ID and then fake being that user. Someone could even just try guess IDs.

I also read that it is better if the ID changes on each page visit. How does this increase security? It seems it just would decrease the amount of time any ID could be used.

Also how would any of this change with a "Remember Me" feature that would be stored for long time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ID you are describing is precisely what the session ID is, except it's handled for you transparently by php (browsers pass along this session ID with the cookie).

The security flaw you are describing is precisely what [firesheep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firesheep) takes advantage of. You can prevent the session ID from being sniffed by making sure that all authenticated requests to your site take place over ssl. This not only includes logging in, it also includes any time an authenticated user tries to access a page (which means the browser will be passing along an authenticated session id).

If a user tries to access a page not via SSL, you should ideally redirect them to an SSL page and give them a new session ID, because the old one could have been compromised.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean that the session ID is handled for me transparently. I do not have to create the ID myself? If so, where do I get it and how would I give them a new one?

Comment: Using the [session functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php) in php, you can initialize reset or destroy sessions,  the php engine automatically assigns each user a unique session id, which is passed back and forth between the server and the browser, you can then store whatever you want in the `$_SESSION` array, every time the user requests a page, your server will look to see if a $_SESSION array exists for that particular cookie and will restore the data.

Answer (score 0):

The key to such a system is that you don't randomly generate the key--you generate it using facts about the user, ones that another client wouldn't have knowledge of--like the user's IP address, user-agent, and session id. Then you make the user authenticate using that key and their session id (which is transparently handled by PHP).